# WPF maintain window size across multiple windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application (using MVVM) which consists of several windows. All windows have the same dimensions specified and open at the centre of the owner screen. The user may also resize the windows. I now require 2 things.

1. To maintain the same size across all windows in case the user resizes any of the windows.
2. To maintain the same position across all windows in case the user drags any of the windows on the screen.

For example, consider the following workflow: MainWindow -> ChildWindow1 -> ChildWindow2. On a button click in the MainWindow, ChildWindow1 opens. On a button click in ChildWindow1, ChildWindow2 opens. The windows open on top of each other, and once you close a window, the previous window would be shown. Suppose the user now resizes ChildWindow2. I want the same to be reflected across MainWindow and ChildWindow1 as well, such that when the user closes ChildWindow2, ChildWindow1 would be of the same size as that of the resized ChildWindow2. This would give users the impression that they're working in the same window.

Also, if the user drags any of the Windows, I want the position of the parent windows to change and correspond to that of the child window.

How can I achieve both these things?

Comment: Are all these windows bound to the same view model? Different instances of the same VM class? Entirely different view models?

Comment: @Tomtom I was really not sure how to proceed, the things that can to mind was if I could bind the window height and width to VM variables, maybe I could take care of the size problem. The other thing I thought I could do was to restrict the user from resizing the windows at all, though I'd really like to keep this as the last resort. I also considered moving from WPF Windows to WPF pages, and open all pages in the same window, but I've never worked with WPF pages, and I'm not sure what new issues it might lead to.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I currently do not have a lot of windows, and they are all bound to the same instance of the same view-model class. However, as the application expands, I plan to use different view-model classes for different parts of the application.

Comment: @Fahad Wouldn't a single window whose contents change be a better UI approach? Rather than giving the user the impression that there is only a single window, and writing lots of code to fake that, why not _just use a single window_ and swap the view when the buttons are clicked?

Comment: @StevenRands I was not aware that something of this sort is possible. Will look it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is using WPF Behaviors, which allow you to encapsulate UI-specific (i.e. non-View Modelish) behavior.

I don't know your exact requirements here (are these the only windows in the application? Are they always synchronized?) but the general approach would be to create a SynchronizedWindowBehavior which I would attach to the different Windows.

This behavior will access some sort of central WindowSynchronizationService, an event aggregator or singleton service (presumably registered in your DI container) which publishes decoupled events. Each instance of the behavior listens to the attached window's Move and Resize events and publishes an event on the aggregator. The other behavior instances consume this event and resize/move their attached windows accordingly.

Here's a good tutorial, both for defining Blend behaviors, hooking them up to a window, and also (specifically) listening to Window resize events: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/09/a-wpf-behavior-for-window-resize-events-in-net-35

Comment: A sample code would help greatly, I'm not familiar with WPF Behaviors, will look them up. Or if you could just point me in the right direction with even a link, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class where you can subscribe and invoke actions. This class can look something like:

```
internal class ActionService<T>
{
    private static ActionService<T> instance;
    private readonly List<ServiceAction<T>> registeredActions;

    private ActionService()
    {
        registeredActions = new List<ServiceAction<T>>();       
    }

    internal static ActionService<T> Instance()
    {
        return instance ?? (instance = new ActionService<T>());
    }

    internal void Subscribe(string actionName, Action<T> action)
    {
        registeredActions.Add(new ServiceAction<T>(actionName, action));
    }

    internal void Unsubscribe(string actionName)
    {
        registeredActions.RemoveAll(action => action.ActionName == actionName);
    }

    internal void Invoke(string actionName, T parameter)
    {
        foreach (ServiceAction<T> action in registeredActions.Where(action => action.ActionName == actionName).ToArray())
        {
            action.Action.Invoke(parameter);
        }
    }

    private class ServiceAction<TSub>
    {
        internal ServiceAction(string actionName, Action<TSub> action)
        {
            ActionName = actionName;
            Action = action;
        }

        internal string ActionName { get; private set; }
        internal Action<TSub> Action { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

In the constructor of each ViewModel you can call something like:

```
ActionService<Thickness>.Instance.Subscribe("SizeChanged", SizeChaned);
```

The second parameter is a function so you have to add the following to your ViewModel:

```
private void SizeChanged(Thickness thickness)
{
  // Change the size to the passed value
}
```

Now if anyone changes the size of any window you can call:

```
ActionService<Thickness>.Instance.Invoke("SizeChanged", ACTUALSIZE_AS_THICKNESS);
```

You can use this `ActionService` anywhere you want to communicate over ViewModel- or Model-Borders.